# Proper way to jail user so shell doesn't immediately close

Tags: bash, shell, chroot, jails

Trying to use jailkit on Centos7.  I've installed by source and also used RPM's at http://dries.eu/rpms/jailkit/jailkit, and get the same results.  I am primarily following https://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/howtos_chroot_shell.html, however, have also looked at many other documents.

**Step 1:** Creating the Jail.  Should I also include `jk_lsh`?  More on this later.  Also, not a big deal, but do you recommend using the `-k` option to make links instead of copying them?  Note that several files did not exist.

```
[root@mybox ~]# jk_init -v -j /home/jail basicshell editors extendedshell netutils ssh sftp scp | grep 'do not exist'
Source file(s) /lib/libnsl.so.1 do not exist
Source file(s) /lib/libnss*.so.2 do not exist
Source file(s) /etc/bash.bashrc do not exist
Source file(s) /usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8 do not exist
Source file(s) /etc/vimrc do not exist
Source file(s) /etc/joe do not exist
Source file(s) /etc/bash.bashrc do not exist
Source file(s) /usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8 do not exist
Source file(s) /usr/share/mc do not exist
Source file(s) /etc/vimrc do not exist
Source file(s) /etc/joe do not exist
Source file(s) /lib/libnss_dns.so.2 do not exist
Source file(s) /usr/lib/sftp-server do not exist
Source file(s) /usr/lib/misc/sftp-server do not exist
Source file(s) /usr/libexec/sftp-server do not exist
Source file(s) /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server do not exist
Source file(s) /usr/lib/sftp-server do not exist
Source file(s) /usr/lib/misc/sftp-server do not exist
Source file(s) /usr/libexec/sftp-server do not exist
Source file(s) /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server do not exist
[root@mybox ~]#
```

**Step 2:** Adding user to the jail.  Can't add a user as `/usr/sbin/jk_lsh` wasn't added.  I can either add it using `jk_init`, or specify the shell for the user using `-s /bin/bash` (which seems appropriate as later need to change it).  I've tried both.

```
[root@mybox ~]# jk_jailuser -m -v -j /home/jail testuser1
invalid shell, /home/jail/usr/sbin/jk_lsh does not exist
enter jail directory: /home/jail
invalid shell, /home/jail/usr/sbin/jk_lsh does not exist
enter jail directory: ^C
aborted..
[root@mybox ~]#
# add jk_lsh and jail users...
[root@mybox ~]# cat /etc/passwd | grep testuser
testuser1:x:1002:1002::/home/jail/./home/testuser1:/usr/sbin/jk_chrootsh
testuser2:x:1003:1003::/home/jail/./home/testuser2:/usr/sbin/jk_chrootsh
[root@mybox ~]# cat /home/jail/etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
testuser1:x:1002:1002::/home/testuser1:/usr/sbin/jk_lsh
testuser2:x:1003:1003::/home/testuser2:/bin/bash
[root@mybox ~]#
```

**Step 3:**  Log on as new user.  Attempting to log on as either testuser1 or testuser2, the shell is immediately closed.

```
[root@mybox ~]# tail -6 /var/log/secure
Sep  7 14:12:24 mybox sshd[2615]: Accepted password for testuser1 from 11.22.333.444 port 62008 ssh2
Sep  7 14:12:24 mybox sshd[2615]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user testuser1 by (uid=0)
Sep  7 14:12:24 mybox sshd[2615]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user testuser1
Sep  7 14:12:36 mybox sshd[2623]: Accepted password for testuser2 from 11.22.333.444 port 62009 ssh2
Sep  7 14:12:36 mybox sshd[2623]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user testuser2 by (uid=0)
Sep  7 14:12:37 mybox sshd[2623]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user testuser2
[root@mybox ~]#
```

**My Hack Workaround:**  When installing from source and using `jk_init -k ..`, I executed `jk_cp -v -f -j /home/jail /bin/bash` before adding a user, and doing so prevented the shell from immediately closing.  Not sure why this is necessary, or whether the -k flag or needing to do from source made the change.  Regardless, it seems to me needing to do this step probably is a poor workaround.

**Last Minor Issue:**  Not a big deal, but also get these errors when updating:

```
[root@mybox ~]# jk_update -j /home/jail -d
ERROR:  while scannign dir /home/jail/lib/: No such file or directory
ERROR:  while scannign dir /home/jail/opt/: No such file or directory
[root@mybox ~]#
```

**My Question:**  What is the proper way to jail a user so the shell doesn't immediately close?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this, it's easy to use.

you can set a user into jail within only 3 steps.

```
1. add user to system
2. create a jail with jail-shell command.
3. set user into jail with jail-shell command.
```

Here is the tool: https://github.com/pymumu/jail-shell

**NOTE:** I'm the developer of this tool, so this is a bit of self promotion.

> Nick Peng = pymumu